# Error when trying to mount harddrive

Tags: usb, sudo

Hello I have tried to mount my hard drive to a folder.

First I created a folder with mkdir, named /media/movies
but when I tried to mount it using

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=pi,gid=pi /dev/sda1 /media/movies/
```

I got the message

> Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened. The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there any output from `mount | grep sda1`?

Comment: It's probably already auto-mounted. What OS are you running and do you use Kodi or XBMC?

Comment: hello, i followed this tutorial http://www.techjawab.com/2013/06/how-to-setup-mount-auto-mount-usb-hard.html on how to mount, and i got to the part where im suppose to edit the fstab file where should i put the code that they show on the site?

Comment: Take a step back. Without doing any of the things in your linked reference: what's the output to the command goldilock suggested in the first comment? Also please state your OS and what programs you're running. E.g. if you have a media center like kodi the harddrive will be automounted and trying to mount it again manually will fail.

Comment: Try un-mounting and mounting the device back again.
Hope that helps. :)